# Como pegar dados de dentro de um array com foreach em php

Tags: php

estou recebendo dados de um formulário de cadastro. Um desses dados é um array...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esse array de objetos, (dates), poderá ter inúmeras posições/quantidades. Na imagem acima, testei com esses 2.
Estou tentando fazer um foreach para pegar os dados que vem no array dates, porém, não estou conseguindo.

Com esse código:

```
$dates = $data->dates;
print_r($dates);

foreach($dates as $key){
    echo $day = $key->date;
}
```

e só estou conseguindo exibir as datas e unidas

11/06/202112/06/2021

Preciso separar os dados da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?
Já me disseram para usar dois foreachs, mas não estou conseguindo.
Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!
Consegui executar chamando a referencia por brackets

```
$i = 1;
foreach($dates as $key){
    echo 'data_' . $i . '&nbsp' . $key->date . '<br>';
    echo 'quantidade_'. $i . '&nbsp' . $key->quantity . '<br>'; 
    echo 'valor_'. $i . '&nbsp' . $key->value. '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
//saida
//data_1 11/06/2021
//quantidade_1 2
//valor_1 100
//
//data_2 12/06/2021
//quantidade_2 2
//valor_2 150
```

Comment: Vou tentar, valeu Jhonata.

Comment: Rodei as linhas e deu isso:
"<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Web/eudirijo/api/rentcars/availability.php:29"
A linha 29 é essa abaixo
echo 'data_' . $i . '&nbsp' . $key['date'] . '<br>'

Comment: Olá, editei o código, na hora de testar criei arrays ao invés de Obj. Creio que agora vai funcionar no seu código! Desculpe pelo vacilo.

Answer (score -2):

Voce pode transformar os objetos dentro do array em array e entao executar os `foreach`

```
//Transforma os Object dentro do Array em Array
$tudoArray = json_decode(json_encode($data->dates), true);

//translation
$k_trans = array(
    'date'      => 'Data',
    'value'     => 'Valor',
    'quantity'  => 'Quantidade',
);

$i = 0;
foreach($tudoArray as $values1){
    $i++;
    foreach($values1 as $key => $value2){
        echo "{$k_trans[$key]}_{$i} {$value2}<br>";
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```